Why is the Cloud File API marking a file as needing to be synced when it is opened?
I am using the Cloud File API as a sync client and to track version history.
I noticed that I recieve a notification that a file's content has changed when I open a dehydrated\cloud-only structured storage file type, such as Powerpoint (.ppt) or Excel (.xls), with this call:
StgOpenStorageEx(fullPath, STGM.STGM_DIRECT_SWMR | STGM.STGM_READWRITE | STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE, STGFMT_DOCFILE, defaul, default, default, IID_IStorage, out var iptr)

The Cloud Filter API marks the filer as needing to be synced. CfUpdatePlaceholder(HFILE fileHandle, IntPtr fsMetadata, IntPtr fileIdentity, uint fileIdentityLength,CF_FILE_Range[]? dehydrateRangeArray, uint dehydrateRangeCount, CF_UPDATE_FLAGS updateFlags, ref long updateUsn, IntPtr overlapped) is triggered when this happens.
Why might this be occurring on a read for these special file types? (Edit: Why does the callback indicate that the file is modified when there hasn't been any actual modification?)
References:

Cloud Filter Api
Structured Storage Types and StgOpenStorageEx

Expectation: Opening structured storage file for read should not be notified of a content changed event.

STGM_READWRITE doesn't open the file for reading.

@IInspectable Perhaps that call is a bit misleading. Although the call includes that flag, there has not been any actual modification or write to the file.

That's probably not correct. As I understand Structured Storage uses the Compound File Binary (CFB) format. This is a virtual file system inside of a file. To prevent concurrent modification a request to open the file for write access does indeed write to special sectors in this virtual file system.

@IInspectable Thank you for your insight. I'll look more into the resource you shared.

I wonder then how OneDrive knows not to upload a new version of these files in this situation

What creates/modifies/deletes placeholders is the .exe (the "Storage Provider Sync Root Manager") that rules some sync engine using the Cloud Filter API (the most known one being OneDrive). The CF API doesn't do much by itself, beyong notifying this exe using callbacks. CfUpdatePlaceholder is called by the .exe and the rules it uses depends on how it's coded.  Usually the .exe uses ReadDirectoryChangesW to be notified of changes in the file. I guess a change is triggered by ReadDirectoryChangesW when you use StgOpenStorageExe the way you do. Easy to check with .NET FileSystemWatcher for ex.)

Thanks Simon. Even if we could eliminate the notification, it is slightly troubling that the operating system has already changed the status icon to "Needs sync". I think it does this, not our code via the callback. Thus, we have to do something to mark this file back as "in sync".

@MichaelFoster Everything works as designed. Opening a Structured Storage file for write access modifies the file. The CF API is correct in notifying about the file change and the UI (File Explorer, presumably) faithfully represents the changed state.

I think you're making a confusion between the file system, the CF API (which sits in the kernel), the Shell (Explorer or common dialogs being its usual visible parts), and the Sync Root Manager (like OneDrive in the OneDrive case). It's usually the SRM and the Shell which do most work, not the OS/the CF API. Once the file has been changed, the SRM must synchronize file (whatever that means for it) update place holders, notifies who needs to be, and the Shell will change statuses accordingly. And if the SRM .exe doesn't run, nothing works (StgOpenStorageEx will even fail).

The sentences "The Cloud Filter API marks the file as needing to be synced" and  "CfUpdatePlaceholder is triggered" are somewhat nonsensical. CF API is not a sync engine, it does nothing for synchronization, it understands files, placeholders (attributes) and file hydration/dehydration, that's about it. The sync engine is the SRM (ex: OneDrive.exe in OneDrive case) which is to be implemented by a developer, and it's a lot of work

What is confusing is, let's say our product (presumably the SRM) is not running and I edit a file that has been previously hydrated. The result is the icon will change to the "need sync" icon. So, i'm not sure who set that icon.
Now take the case when we are running. IInspectable has given us info to suggest that the file has actually been modified. Yet the hash value of the file hasn't changed. Can we implement a optimization to not upload if the hash hasn't changed? Sure.  But it seems almost like a bug that a file was marked as needing sync that hasn't changed from a hash perspective.

I did a test with the application when running, the SRM, where without changing the placeholder via CfUpdatePlaceholder, the sync icon/status is changed when the structured storage file is opened. As an aside, I do notice an exception being thrown ("The cloud file provider is not running") when using the StgOpenStorageEx call when the SRM is not running as you mentioned, Simon, but only when the file is dehydrated.

Does it occur for all file types? I suspect it does change something but not the file content as far as STGM_READWRITE is concerned.
